# Eclipse Path Variable to Output folder

Tags: eclipse

I need to start an external tool in eclipse, which starts with some arguments. One of them revers to the output file. My problem is, that I have more than one build configuration, so I have multiple output folders, but I want to use just one external tool config.

[External tool config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAse1.png)

Is there A way, where I can set the output folder as a dynamic variable, which depends on the selected build config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a variable config_name:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1076833/

> ${config_name} of the current project is given by:
> ${config_name:${ProjName}}